# Docker Microsoft SQL Server - PHP Artisan Migrate - Could not find driver

Tags: sql-server, laravel, docker

I am running an Alpine Linux image and I've added this to the dockerfile:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add curl gnupg

RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/msodbcsql17_17.7.2.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/mssql-tools_17.7.1.1-1_amd64.apk

RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/msodbcsql17_17.7.2.1-1_amd64.sig
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/mssql-tools_17.7.1.1-1_amd64.sig

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc  | gpg --import -
RUN gpg --verify msodbcsql17_17.7.2.1-1_amd64.sig msodbcsql17_17.7.2.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN gpg --verify mssql-tools_17.7.1.1-1_amd64.sig mssql-tools_17.7.1.1-1_amd64.apk

RUN apk add --allow-untrusted msodbcsql17_17.7.2.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN apk add --allow-untrusted mssql-tools_17.7.1.1-1_amd64.apk
```

[This is based off what the Microsoft website said](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#alpine17)

In Laravel I have my database connection set to `sqlsrv`

When I shell into my app and run `php artisan migrate:status` I get the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

could not find driver (SQL: select * from sysobjects where type = 'U' and name = migrations)
```

Am I missing a config setting somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most probably because you only install [Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#alpine17), but did not install [Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server for PHP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15#installing-on-alpine):

> **Install prerequisites (Alpine)**
>
> Install the ODBC driver for Alpine by following the instructions on the Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux). Make sure to also install the unixodbc-dev package (`sudo apk add unixodbc-dev`). It's used by the pecl command to install the PHP drivers.
> **Install the PHP drivers for Microsoft SQL Server (Alpine)**
>
> ```
> sudo pecl install sqlsrv
> sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
> sudo su
> echo extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so >> `php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`/10_pdo_sqlsrv.ini
> echo extension=sqlsrv.so >> `php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`/00_sqlsrv.ini
> ```